# A sigma algebra with countably infinite atoms does not exist

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory

I am self-studying Rene Schilling's Measure Theory book:

Show that there cannot be a σ-algebra $A$ which contains countably infinitely many sets.
The outline for the proof goes as follows:

We first show that such the set $A$ contains |$\mathbb{N}$| disjoint atoms. (this is the bulk of the proof)

Then, the solution manual says: "Since $A$ contains all countable unions of sets from $A_0$ [the set of all atoms], and ***since there are more than countably many such unions, it is clear*** that $|A| > |\mathbb{N}|$." (At which point the proof concludes, since it's a contradiction, as the sigma algebra itself must have cardinality of $|\mathbb{N}|$)

But it is not clear to me that the countable unions of countably infinite atoms are uncountably infinite.

In fact, it seems to me an extension of the proof that shows a bijection from the rationals to the naturals:
I could list out the atoms in a grid, and take the union of the first atom and the second atom, then the union of the first atom and the third atom, and then I could enumerate all $|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|$ two-atom unions this way. Next, I would use an inductive argument to count all the three-atom unions, and so on and so forth. In the end, I would still end up with a countably infinite number of sets, wouldn't I?

Thanks a bunch for the help--I wish I had a prof. that I could ask questions of, but Math Stack Exchange is a great second!

Comment: Hint: identity a binary number between $0$ and $1$ with the subset of the natural numbers that tells you where the $1's$ are placed.

Comment: Notice that $A$ contain the power set of $\mathbb N$, and it's well know that the power set of $\mathbb N$ is not countable.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in Surb's comment.
$A$ contains $|\mathbb{N}|$ disjoint atoms.
Therefore, the countable union of these atoms is the power set of such $|\mathbb{N}|$ disjoint atoms.
By Cantor's Theorem, this power set must have greater than $|\mathbb{N}|$ cardinality, which results in a contradiction, as this is greater than the assumed  cardinality of $A$.